# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number' while passing the id

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue whenever I pass the item's id in OnPressItem inside the Text, the (item?.id) shows undefined is not assignable to type 'number. What other way can I declare id is the number?

```
export interface MeetingListProps {
  data?: Meetings
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
  onPressItem: (id: number) => void //here define the onPressItem

const { onPressItem } = props
}

const { data, loading, error } = useGetMeetingsQuery
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data?.meetings &&
        data.meetings.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.item} onPress={() => onPressItem(item?.id)}>{item?.title}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use optional chaining (`?.` syntax) the result value can be either your value (item.id) or undefined if the item is null or undefined. So the type of `item?.id` is `number | undefined`. The simple solution is to remove the optional chaining operator if your array does not have null-ish values inside, or check for the item before calling the function onPressItem

```
onPress={() => item ? onPressItem(item.id) : {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to tell Typescript to expect a number if item exists by supplying a type for item.

```
export interface MeetingListProps {
  onPressItem: (id: number) => void; //here define the onPressItem
}
type IItem = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};
type IQuery = () => {
  data: { meetings: IItem[] };
  loading: boolean;
  error: {};
};

const useGetMeetingsQuery: IQuery = () => {
  return { data: { meetings: [] }, loading: true, error: {} };
};

export default function Item(props: MeetingListProps) {
  const { onPressItem } = props;

  const { data, loading, error } = useGetMeetingsQuery();

  return (
    <div>
      {data?.meetings &&
        data.meetings.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <p onClick={() => onPressItem(item?.id)}>{item?.title}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-sun-7vzbhu?file=/src/Item.tsx)